# How to search for a Char in a txt file using C++

Tags: c++

I need help searching a text file for a specific character which is the start of every item which I need to read in. Pretending it is a `%`, I need to start at the first `%` and continue reading (maybe in lines) until I reach the next `%` and save it into a string.

I am unsure how to proceed. Do I need to convert everything to char or is there a way to search that I am unaware of?

Comment: I do, but it will be nice to see some code and what you have tried

Comment: Do you know what pretending exactly mean?

Comment: ... but does that helps: [`std::string::find_first_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of)?

Comment: It says it in the question

Comment: It is kind of said in the title, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) for this.  `getline` will read until it reaches a delimiter.  You can specify your special character as that delimiter.  The first call to `getline` will read everything up to the special character and then the second call will read the rest until you reach it again.

```
std::ifstream fin("some_text_file.txt");
std::string data;
std::getline(fin, data, '%'); // find start
std::getline(fin, data, '%'); // read data;
```

If you need to get the lines between the two special characters then you can feed the string you got with `getline` into a [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) and then you can read each line in that stream.

```
std:stringstream ss(data)
std::string line;
while (std::getline(ss, line))
{
    //do something with line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `getline(is, myStr, '#')`, where `is` is a string stream and `myStr` is the output. This will read in the stream until it finds the delimiter `#`, and then store everything up to (but not including the `#`). You can then repeat this and just store every other entry to only get ones in between pairs of `#` signs.